# How much is the performance overhead for awaiting an already fulfilled Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

While doing code reviews, I've recently come across such kind of code blocks:

```
const promises = [];
const data = [];
for (let piece of pieces) {
  for (let chunk of piece) {
    promises.push(execute(chunk)); //execute returns a promise which is not yet fulfilled
  }
  data = await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Here `pieces` is an array of arrays. Note that due to certain constraints we *cannot `await` all Promises at once*, hence this sort of chunking.

In my feedback, I write that this appears to be an anti-pattern as we are also awaiting Promises *which were resolved in the previous iterations* and the following is the proper way of handling such scenarios:

```
const data = [];
for (let piece of pieces) {
  const promises = [];
  for (let chunk of piece) {
    promies.push(execute(chunk)); //execute returns a promise which is not yet fulfilled
  }
  data.push(... await Promise.all(promises));
}
```

At the end, `data` will be the same in both cases.

I understand how `data` is being populated in both cases. I would like to know how much is the performance overhead of awaiting an already fulfilled promise (which is happening in the first code block) and is it significant?

Comment: the two code blocks are not identical at all ... the first one will end up with less data than the second in data

Comment: The intent here is pretty unclear. Certainly if this is about gathering to `data` then both listings are likely not that ideal. To clarify comments I've seen here so far example 1 is "re-assigning" the `data` and 2. Is "attempting" to accumulate. Unfortunately it's all a bit "meta" to really understand context here. And without context, any answer really lacks any meaning. Best if the comments cool down and allow the OP to clarify.

Comment: if you take 2nd variant and `await data` outside the loops it would be fastest option

Comment: @MarkMeyer In the end, `data` will be the same in both cases and it's not wrong. I'm concerned with the performance overhead of awaiting promises which were already fulfilled in the previous iterations.

Comment: Sorry @sbmthakur I was distracted by the last part of the code and missed the nesting difference.

Comment: @CertainPerformance no, they are still Promises.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've added some context. Could you review it again?

Comment: you're asking for a code review - there's a site for that

Comment: @JaromandaX  No. I just wanted to be certain that my intent is clear.

Comment: @skyboyer I understand that and I've addressed this in the edit.

Comment: how about running short snippet with 1000 fullfilled Promises created with `Promise.resolve`? there no one answer possible since it depends on amount of Promises, hardware, Node's version and config. yes, there is overhead. No, it's not huge.

Comment: if you have 1k of requests or more I'd worry more about memory that can not be garbage-collected all the way

Comment: There is very little overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overhead is minuscule - it needs to iterate the already fulfilled promise, inspect it, take out the data and put it inside the result array. Assuming native promises, I expect this to be optimised and not need a roundtrip to the event loop, if you had thenables in the array then all of them would need to get resolved to a promise and that promise would need to be awaited asynchronously, taking a toll on the promise job queue.

The overhead in processing time will not be significant compared to the actual asynchronous work done in your `execute` function.

However, no matter how small the overhead is, the issue with the first version of your code is that its runtime complexity is quadratic: `Promise.all` needs to iterate the whole `promises` array every time. The more chunks * pieces you have, the more pronounced the effect will be. I agree with your review feedback and would recommend the second version of the code.

Comment: FWIW, you do still get a round trip through the event loop with native promises. In fact, a simple way to defer an action is to simply `await Promise.resolve()`

Comment: @EricHaynes To be precise, it goes through the microtask queue, not the entire event loop. `await undefined` (or `Promise.resolve()`) is not a replacement for `requestIdleCallback` or `setImmediate` (which you can wrap in a promise if you need to); `while (true) await Promise.resolve()` will freeze the browser.